# Set default layout for new activity to "Linear layout" instead of "Relative layout" in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, code-generation

I usually use Linear layout for most of my activity. I want to make Android studio create Linear layout by default when I create new activity, instead of Relative layout. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make one blank xml file like this .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_trip_detail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Then go to **Window > Store current layout as default** in android studio from top tool bar .This layout will become your default .You can restore your settings by same tab .

Comment: The "Store current layout by default" action stores the default layout of the IntelliJ IDEA toolwindows. It has nothing to do with layouts used for creating Android activities.

Comment: Ya true you need to create separate xml file instead of creating via new activity .

Answer (score 0):

change layout of file to whatever you like in simple.xml.ftl given at below location
:\